# What could be said about the distribution of two iid random variables $X$ and $Y$, given the distribution of $X-Y$?

Tags: probability-distributions

In particular, if the distribution of $X-Y$ is known, can the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ be determined up to some simple transformations e.g. translation and reflection?

Comment: $|Ee^{it(X-Y)}|=|Ee^{itX}|^{2}$. This might help, depending what $Ee^{it(X-Y)}$ is.